# How concatenate a PHP variable into a HTML link?

Tags: javascript, php, html, web-applications

i need to concatenate this variable `$idCantiere` into a href attribute

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="../../../paginaIniziale/sceltaModificaAffidatario.php?idCantiere='.$idCantiere.'">Continua -></a>   `
```

In other words, I need that when I press the `"Continua->"` button, I will be redirected to the HREF page but with the addition, at the end of the link, of the "idCantiere"

Comment: We need to see the wider context of this snippet. Is it in a PHP file? Is it currently being done through `echo` / `print` or is it templated (meaning you are closing / opening your PHP tags or are using short echo `<?=`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="../../../paginaIniziale/sceltaModificaAffidatario.php?idCantiere=<?php echo $idCantiere ?>Continua -></a>
```

What this does is the following:

1. opens `<?php` tags so we can write php.
2. echo your variable in the html template
3. Close the php by `?>`

When you use `echo` in php it will output the value of a variable to the actual HTML file that will be produced. Thus you use echo when you need to output something **dynamic** into the html.

Comment: The only answer which is explaining what is going and that is what is needed, might I suggest that you also link / explain the shortcut syntax of `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possible solutions:

https://www.tehplayground.com/rpPcUnram5TAxdAs

Have fun!

edit:
sorry for that here is the code:

No 1:

```
<?php
$idCantiere = 123;
print '<a class="btn btn-primary" href="../../../paginaIniziale/sceltaModificaAffidatario.php?idCantiere='.$idCantiere.'">Continua -></a>';
?>
```

No 2:

```
<?php
$idCantiere = 123;
?>
....
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="../../../paginaIniziale/sceltaModificaAffidatario.php?idCantiere=<?php print $idCantiere; ?>">Continua -></a>
```